# How can I access a Sharepoint Document Repository with OneDrive for Business API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business, office365apis

I'm trying to write an app that can access documents on a SharePoint teamsite. It is my understanding that OneDrive for Business and a SharePoint teamsite are more or less the same thing. I was thinking the OneDrive for Business API should be able to do this, but so far I have had no luck accessing any documents outside of my OneDrive page.

https://dev.onedrive.com/

I've read that I might be able to use this url

```
https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/{site-path}.
```

But I can't figure out what `{site-path}` is for the root of a team site.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured it out.  You can the following to list the root level folders of a sharepoint site:
https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/{site-path}/_api/v2.0/drive/root/children

Where, if you are looking at the URL of the SharePoint teamsite homepage {tenant} and {site-path} are:

https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/{site-path}/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Home.aspx